# Edit, Clear and set expiry time/date on local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and JavaScript, I already done passing the data from page1.html to page2.html through local storage now i'm trying to do is i want to edit the data on page2.html and also will edit the data on page1.html without going to page1.html(*if i edit the last name on page2.html, the last name that i put on page1.html will also change*) also i want to set an expiry time/date on local storage to delete the data and if i reload or close the window the data on local storage will be deleted.

Here's what I've done so far to test it:

page1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
      function passvalues(){
     var firstname=document.getElementById("first").value;
     var name=document.getElementById("last").value;
        
           var selectext=document.getElementById("mycolor").value;
           
      localStorage.setItem("firstname", firstname);
      localStorage.setItem("lastname", lastname);
      
        localStorage.setItem("colorvalue",selectcolor);
      return true;
      }
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Passing</h1>
<hr/>
<form action="page2.html">
<input type ="text" id="first"/>
<input type ="text" id="last"/>

<select id="mycolor">
                      <option >Color</option>
                      <option>Red</option>
                      <option >Blue</option>
                      <option>Purlpe</option>
                      <option >Green</option>
                    </select>
<input type ="submit" value="Click" onclick="passvalues();"/>
</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
<head>
<center>
<h1>page2</h1>
<hr/>
</head>
<body>
Welcome.. <span id="resultfirst"></span> 
Welcome.. <span id="resultlast"></span> 
Welcome.. <span id="resultcolor"></span> 
<button id="edit">Edit</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById("resultfirst").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("firstname");
    document.getElementById("resultlast").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("lastname");
    
    document.getElementById("resultcolor").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("colorvalue");
</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use setTimeout() to remove or clear items in localstorage